# Is there any specific guidelines for UI in Dell Streak

Tags: android, mobile

I've started designing application for **Dell Streak**..my question is is there any specific resolution for streak device..I tried with 72 pixels..its not that much sharp..also the layout is not aligning properly..to fit the screen size (as the streak is of **800x480** pixels)

Is there any proper guidelines for this means..i'll be glad enough..

Regards,

Jagadish.

Answer (score 0):

There are no device-specific design guidelines. Google rather recommends guidelines for different screen sizes and densities.

You can find an overview [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and for general design guidelines [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html).